# Pandas: what is the best way to replace multiple columns with values from other columns based on the condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to replace the list of columns with other columns based on the condition. Here is the logic: if column A and B are null, then replace the column C, D, E with F, G, H.

```
  df.loc[(df['A'].isna()) & (df['B'].isna()), ['C', 'D', 'E'] = df[['F', 'G', 'H']]
```

But this doesn't actually do anything. What could the issue be in here?

Comment: try `df[['F','G','H']]` at the end (double brackets instead of single)

Comment: @rhug123 sorry for the confusion, the original code was df[['F','G','H']].

Comment: after taking a look, loc will align on df column names. try adding `.to_numpy()` to the end of the double brackets now, and it will not align anymore. they have to be the same shape though

Comment: @rhug123 the size of the dataframe is filtered based on the conditions so they are not same shape.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a slicker way of doing it but this should work

```
df.loc[
    (df['A'].isna()) & (df['B'].isna()), 
    ['C', 'D', 'E']
] = df.loc[
    (df['A'].isna()) & (df['B'].isna()),
    ['F', 'G', 'H']
].values
```